# Alternative way to push into the stack

Tags: c++, stack, push

I developed this program to add and the retrieve 15$ in the stack.
I was wondering is there another more efficient way to write my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int MAX = 100;
    int count;


    stack<int, vector<int> > billStack;

    for (int i=0; i<15; i++) {
        billStack.push(i);      // add 15 bills onto stack
    }

    cout << "The stack has " << billStack.size() << " bills.\n";

    int cash;
    cout << "How many bills to retrieve?\n";
    cin >> cash;
    for (int i = 0; i< cash; i++) {
        billStack.pop();
    }
    cout << "Cash out :" << cash << ". Remaining: " << billStack.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any obviously more efficient way to write this, no.

Comment: This is definitely most efficient version of most inefficient code to deal with such things.

Comment: (I mean, I did see Igor's answer, but I assume you actually want to use a stack for some reason)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions to review working code belong on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that you don't ever use the actual contents of the stack, just its size:

```
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
 int stackSize = 15;
 cout << "The stack has " << stackSize << " bills.\n";

 int cash;
 cout << "How many bills to retrieve?\n";
 cin >> cash;

 stackSize -= cash;
 cout << "Cash out :" << cash << ". Remaining: " << stackSize << endl;
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Uhm, you can dispense with the `stackSize` variable, and also with the `return 0;`. Then the remaining inefficiency is the stream based i/o, which can be replaced with `<stdio.h>` i/o. I think that's it. :)